# intercept web service request/response in original xml format in .net

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, soap

I am calling web services by adding service reference in visual studio project after adding the reference as it generates proxy class and objects to be called rather xml.

I am calling web methods using objects but just wondering what xml request gets created and response xml comes back, how can we see that xmls

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're interested it from a debugging / developer perspective (I.e. not to use in your program), in which case I'd recommend using something like Fiddler to see what's going across the wire.